# why operator == in map comparator function giving problem

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

For std::map, if i use the below comparator,

```
class mmap
{
public:
    bool operator()(const int &lhs, const int &rhs) const
    {
        return lhs == rhs;
    };
};
int main()
{
    std::map<int, char, mmap> cont;
    cont = { { 1, 'a' }, { 2, 'b' }, { 3, 'c' }, { 4, 'd' }, { 5, 'e' } };
std::cout << cont.size() << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

it is giving the output of size as 1. It should be 5. If in comparator instead of using == if i use < or > it is returning the correct size. Can anybody please help, why it is giving wrong results.

Comment: The comparator you pass to `std::map` needs to provide a strict weak ordering. `operator>` and `operator<` both are for `int`s, `operator==` is not.

Comment: I think you already know the problem (when you use < or > it returns the correct size)? Do you want to ask about what the implementation does internally (although it is undefined behavior)

Answer (score 0):

`std::map` does not allow duplicate keys.  How does it know if a key is duplicate when it only has a single comparison function?  It's duplicate when `comp(a,b)` and `comp(b,a)` both return `False`, meaning one doesn't come before the other.  Your comparison function does that any time the keys are unequal, so the duplicates are rejected.

Answer (score 0):

A program with *defined* behavior that uses `std::map` should have a Compare functior that fulfills the [Compare requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). Yours don't.

> why operator == in map comparator function giving problem

Because you haven't made it fulfill the requirements. Do that - no problems